# Button to Recognize Selected Path

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview, ibaction, didselectrowatindexpath

Trying to have a button confirm the index selected in a tableview with a special class. This is how I would NSLog the result of the selected index.

```
- (void)selector:(IZValueSelectorView *)valueSelector didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)index {
NSLog(@"Selected index %d",index);
}
```

but I'm not sure how I'd confirm that with a button since the button uses an IBAction.

I want an alert to pop up once they click the button. This is what I have so far, but I get an error since it doesn't recognize what index means:

```
- (IBAction)submit:(id)sender {


UIAlertView *submit = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Submit"

                       message:(@"Are you sure you want to submit %i", index)

                      delegate:self

                      cancelButtonTitle:@"No"

                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
[submit show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to be able to select a row, and then press a button somewhere, to confirm that you selected it, and you don't know how to get the selected index, correct?

If you have an `IBOutlet` pointing to the tableView, you can get the selected index path, using:

```
self.myTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
```

*Or his cousin, `indexPathsForSelectedRows` for multiple selection*

Also, be noted, that if you have a `UIButton` inside a cell, and you tap on the button, it doesn't mean that the cell will get selected. Selection occurs when the cell gets touched-up inside (aka. it gets blue coloured).

Of course, the cleanest and easiest method, would to avoid using a button entirely, and just using the `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    // Do the UIAlertView thing here
}
```